# Folder picker - subscript out of range

Tags: vba

I copied this code from the internet, but I can't get it to run.  Comes up with the error message:

```
Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range
```

This is the code.  Can anyone tell me how to resolve?

```
Sub SelectFolder()
Dim Get_Path As String

MsgBox "Click OK to locate folder where you want the PDF reports saved."

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    If .Show <> 0 Then
      Get_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(17, 7).Value = Get_Path
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is that `Worksheets("Sheet1")` is throwing the error because you don't have a sheet with the name `"Sheet1"`.  Just change that line to match the name of the sheet that you have.

Comment: You'll need to site the source and give attribution to this code that you've copied. See [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the below code. It worked for me.

```
Sub folSelect()
    'Below line opens prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        If .Show = -1 Then 
            selFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If selFolder = "" Then 
        MsgBox "Please Choose the folder"
    Else: worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(17, 7) = selFolder
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The

`Subscript out of range (Error 9)`

error is thrown when the index or element reference supplied to an array or collection is outside of the defined accepted range:

> Elements of arrays and members of collections can only be accessed within their defined ranges.

The 'subscript' part comes from the mathematical notation for an index: a<sub>i</sub>, which uses a subscript.

In your code, the `Worksheets` collection doesn't have an element called `Sheet1`, and so the error is being thrown.

You can refer to element of a collection by a number, and so as long as you have at least one Worksheet open, the following always works, regardless of the worksheet name:

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(17, 7).Value = Get_Path
```

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/subscript-out-of-range-error-9
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_notation
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets